# Logging in using Requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello I am trying to login to https://www.neighborwho.com using `Requests` for `Python` but with my code the website response keeps telling me that it cannot find any user with my username when in fact I can login using normal browser manually. I know I could use a headless browser or maybe `lxml` or `mechanicalsoup` etc but I am learning `python` and `requests` right now so want to see if it can be done in `requests`

Here is my code:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.neighborwho.com/api/v5/session'
payload = {'user[email]': 'my_username',
           'user[password]': 'my_password'}

headers = {'referer': 'https://www.neighborwho.com/app/login',
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
           'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'origin': 'https://www.neighborwho.com', 
           'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
           'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
           'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 
           'content-length': '451', 
           'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 
           'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin'
           }

s = requests.Session()
resp = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
401
{"session":{"errors":"We do not see an account that matches that  
email/password combination. For security reasons we may occasionally reset 
passwords. If you have an account that matches the email address
\"my_username\" and need to reset your password, please use the link
below."},"meta":{"status":401}}
```

Comment: is there an API documentation? how are you _supposed_ to authenticate?

Comment: oh. the error message seems to suggest the user/password combination is wrong... :)

Comment: check if the payload username and password match with the actual username and password used by you to login on the website

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the payload correctly? It looks like it is `"login-email" `and `"login-password"` instead

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, trust me the credentials are correct, double, triple checked them. It's weird that it keeps giving me that error. Also, unfortunately there is no API. Also, when I put the `login-email` and `login-password` it doesnt work at all. I saw those two using the inspect element in browser. But when I check the Request Headers in the browser they specifically say  `user[email]` and `user[password]`. I also tried to use lxml, machinesoup, requests-html. The last resort is Selenium but there is recaptcha so that might not work either.